# Threadsafety in SwingWorker - Updating JTable in a Threadsafe way

Tags: java, thread-safety, swingworker

I have a list of travel offers that I read and parsed from a XML file and added them to my GUI using JTable. I also have some update functionalities (at interval and instantly on click) that updates the GUI as soon as new offers are added to the XML. My aim is to add the offers in the GUI in thread safe way.

This is the class (UpdateData.java) where i perform doInBackground() using Swingworker and more concern about safety. (Other classes are also shown below if anyone is interested to take a deeper look) **Can SwingUtilities.invokeLater() be used to make it thread-safe? Does overriding Swingworkers done(), execute() and process() will help in some way to achieve safety? In that case how? (newbie at thread prog)** (Other classes are given below if anyone is interested to get a deeper look). Some Help / Feedback will be highly appreciated.

Class: **UpdateData.java**

```
public class UpdateData extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

    private ArrayList<RawTravelData> listOfOffer;
    private TravelData offerData;
    private XMLReader parseData;
    //the controller
    private ControlUpdate updtController;

    //constructor
    public UpdateData(TravelData o, ControlUpdate offerController) {
        updtController = offerController;
        parseData = new XMLReader();
        offerData = o;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        listOfOffer = parseData.fetchData();
        offerData.setData(listOfOffer);
        updtController.setOfferArray(listOfOffer);

        return null;
    }

}
```

Class: **RawTravelData.java**

```
public class RawTravelData {

    private String destination = "";
    private String travelDate = "";
    private int currPrice;

    //empty constructor
    public RawTravelData() {

    }

    //setters ad getters for destination, travel date and currprise

}
```

Class: **TravelData.java**

```
public class TravelData extends AbstractTableModel {

    //the table header strings
    private String[] colNames = { "Destination", "Date", "Price", "Details" };
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //arraylist of the offer data
    private ArrayList<RawTravelData> offerList;

    //constructor
    public TravelData(ArrayList<RawTravelData> rtd) {
        offerList = rtd;
    }

    //second constructor to create empty list
    public TravelData() {
        offerList = new ArrayList<RawTravelData>();
    }

    //add the list
    public void setData(ArrayList<RawTravelData> o) {
        offerList = o;
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    //get the offer list
    public ArrayList<RawTravelData> getOfferList() {
        return offerList;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return String.class;
        case 1:
            return Integer.class;
        case 2:
            return String.class;
        case 3:
            return String.class;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return offerList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        switch (arg1) {
        case 0:
            return offerList.get(arg0).getDestination();
        case 1:
            return offerList.get(arg0).getPrice();
        case 2:
            return offerList.get(arg0).getTravelDate();
        case 3:
            return "Details";
        default:
            break;
        }
        return "null";
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return colNames[col];
    }

}
```

Class: **XMLReader.java**

```
public class XMLReader {

    //Method to fetch and read all the data from the XML file
    public ArrayList<RawTravelData> fetchData() {

       //parse data and return as arraylist of offers

        return arrayOfOffer;
    }
}
```

Class: **ControlUpdate.java**

```
//This class is responsible for controlling the updating of the offer data in the background
public class ControlUpdate {

    private TablePanel tablePane;
    private ArrayList<RawTravelData> offerArray;
    //..

    //Constructor
    public ControlUpdate(TablePanel tablePane) {
        settingsVal = new SaveSettings();

        this.tablePane = tablePane;
        tablePane.getOfferTable().addMouseListener(
                new TableSortListener(tablePane.getOfferTable(), this));
        runUpdateTask();
        setUpdateInterval(settingsVal.readSettings());
    }


    //run the updates
    private void runUpdateTask() {
        //used Timer and ScheduledThreadPool
    }

    //get the table panel
    public TablePanel getTablePanel() {
        return tablePane;
    }

    //setting the list to a new offer list for the updater
    public void setOfferArray(ArrayList<RawTravelData> rtd) {
        offerArray = rtd;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All modifications of Components and their models need to be performed in the AWT event dispatch thread, not in a background thread.  The second and third lines of your doInBackground method should be moved to the `done` method, which [is guaranteed to be executed in the AWT event thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done--).

It is also customary to have the SwingWorker's value type be the data you're obtaining in the background.

```
public class UpdateData
extends SwingWorker<List<RawTravelData>, Integer> {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected List<RawTravelData> doInBackground() throws Exception {
        return parseData.fetchData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            List<RawTravelData> listOfOffer = get();

            offerData.setData(listOfOffer);
            updtController.setOfferArray(listOfOffer);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Someone wants us to exit cleanly.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @VGR !!! btw, I used 'ArrayList' as the datatype, are you recommending to use 'List' instead or did you just shorten the expression?